# Kotlin - Use property access syntax issue

Tags: android, kotlin

Well I have a WebView, and the following property setting works:

```
webview.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
```

but not this one:

```
webview.settings.appCacheEnabled = false
```

Instead, I have to use the old way:

```
webview.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false)
```

Can you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: Not every method in kotlin provides access syntax, it depends on many factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters):

> Note that, if the Java class only has a setter, it will not be visible as a property in Kotlin, because Kotlin does not support set-only properties at this time.

If you look at the `WebSettings` abstract class, you'll see it only has `public abstract void setAppCacheEnabled(boolean flag);` method and no getters for this property, hence Kotlin doesn't allow using a property access syntax here.

Actually, it's worth noting that while creating synthetic property, not only Kotlin looks for setter and getter methods that follow Java conventions, but it also infers property's type from the getter which comes in play in case of subclasses overriding getter methods that return more specific type than their superclasses.